# How do i programmatically select range of colors

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If its possible, i want to select blue colors only and put em into array or something. I am thinking colors from light blue to deep blue.

Comment: How many shades of blue?

Comment: i want such blue colors that represent the sky

Comment: Select blue colors from what?  And do what with them once you've got them?

Comment: i want the hex values if its possible. I want to create the sky with the colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want something like this:

http://www.workwithcolor.com/blue-color-hue-range-01.htm

This gets you quite a few colors but you might want to look at just creating a color picker or something if you want even more.

Comment: i have a color picker, but i was hoping that i could just select the blue ones from like 001 to 050 or something

Comment: @dandvto - in this case, you should probably create an array and load it into a drop-down or something like that.  The link I included will give you a good list of shades of blue.  However, the total possibilities are almost endless so you really don't want to include every shade without changing your control to something like  a bound listbox.

Answer (score 3):

A very simplistic approach:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 255).Select(x => Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, x))
```

You could only take every 10th step and also mix in red and green shades.